# Java: Convert bool array into a single int

Tags: java, integer, boolean, bit-manipulation

I have a boolean array (length = 2) that I want to concat and convert to an integer so that individual bits inside the integer would represent values from the boolean array:

```
[false, false] = 0
[false, true] = 1
[true, false] = 2
[true, true] = 3
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work:

```
int n = (a[0] ? 2 : 0) + (a[1] ? 1 : 0);
```

If you want a more general solution:

```
int n = 0, l = a.length;
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    n = (n << 1) + (a[i] ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Haha - yours is more elegant. +1

Answer (score 9):

Generic way for any-length array (although only the last 32 elements make a difference, since ints are 32 bits):

```
int booleansToInt(boolean[] arr){
    int n = 0;
    for (boolean b : arr)
        n = (n << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: neat - I always forget about that version of `for`

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = (array[0] ? 2 : 0) +  (array[1] ? 1 : 0);
```

General solution for length != 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = {true, true, false};
    int number = 0;
    int j = array.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i])
            number += 1 << j--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 0;
for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(array[i])
  {  
    int exponent = (array.length - 1 - i)
    number += Math.pow( 2, exponent );
  }
}
```

Comment: You do know that `Math.pow(2, n) === 2 << n`, if `n` is an integer?

Comment: That is true, and an excellent point.  I figured I'd leave this up for Google viewers' sakes.  It is more readable to a beginner.  Later, they can move on to bit shifting to speed things up.